# Как заставить слайдер в теме на WordPress двигаться?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, слайдер

У меня есть сайт на ВордПрессе egmrm.ru, там в теме есть слайдер, который я хочу анимировать. Что нужно прописать в дополнительный стилях, чтобы слайды менялись?

Answer (score 2):

У вас в теме [slick-слайдер](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Судя по коду, где-то в настройках темы должен быть параметр, включающий автопрокрутку.

Если такой параметр не нашли, найдите в шаблоне главной страницы блок с классом `.wpg-slider` и добавьте ему атрибут data-autoplay="yes".

Comment: Не могу найти этот блок в шаблонах...